# Nested List in Angular JS - Cant figure out how to do

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm extremely newbe for angular JS.

Im creating an simple web app to learn angular JS.

I have a main list that contains various categories of plants. For example, Fruits, Vegetables etc.. to get these data out from the MySQL data base I'm using a PHP script.

When used clicks on a category I need to expand a list that contains names of the plants in that category. For example if user clicks 'Fruits' it expands a list contains "Mango", "Apple", "Banana" etc.. This also done by a PHP script. For the script i need to pass the category ID as an URL parameter

EG. select_category.php?cat_id=1

Final list should be like follow

- Fruits

  - Mango
  - Banana
  - Apple
- Vegetables
- herbals

Following shows the HTML/JS page that I'm using.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>   
<title>Test Display</title>
<body>
    <div ng-app="cat_display" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="x in plant_cat">
        <button value={{x.cat_id}} type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="get_plants(x.cat_id)">{{x.cat_name}}</button> </br>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="y in plant_cat.plant">{{y.plant_name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>


<script>
    var app= angular.module('cat_display',[]);
    var get_all_plant_cats = function($scope,$http)
    {
        //get plat categories
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/Aggry/select_plant_categories.php")
            .then(function(response){
            $scope.plant_cat = response.data.records;
        });
        //get plants
        $scope.get_plants = function(cat_id)
        {
          $http.get("http://localhost:8080/Aggry/select_plant.php?cat_id="+cat_id)
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.plant_cat.plant = response.data.records;                  
            });
        }
    };

    app.controller('customersCtrl',get_all_plant_cats);
</script>
```

But this is not working as expected.

When I'm clicking on one category it expand all the lists.

I have tried all most all the examples in Stack overflow. I didn't have any luck because, my scenario is totally different. In my case i need to send a parameter to PHP script to select necessary data.

Please help me to figure out this.

This is the JSON that generated by select_plant_cat.PHP (Select * plant categories)

```
{"records":[{"cat_id":"1","cat_name":"විසිතුරු මල්"},{"cat_id":"2","cat_name":"ඖෂධිය පැල"},{"cat_id":"3","cat_name":"පලතුරු පැල"},{"cat_id":"4","cat_name":"එළවලු පැල"}]}
```

This is the JSON that generated by select_plant.PHP?cat_id=1 (Select * plants where cat_id=1)

```
{"records":[{"plant_id":"1","plant_min_price":"300.00","plant_max_price":"","plant_short_description":"පඳුරු ගැටපිච්ච මල් සහිතව බන්දුන්ගතාකළ පැල","plant_description":"සුදු පැහැති මල් සහිත මධ්‍යම ප්‍රමාණයේ ගැට පිච්ච පැල කොම්පෝස්ට් පොහොර යොදා බඳුන් ගතකර ඇත.බිම සිටුවීමට හෝ බන්දුනේම තබා ගැනීමට උචිතය","plant_image_url":"https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2e/38/ce/2e38ce89db5e470c8e6e527738fd18a5.jpg","plant_availability":"true","plant_name":"ගැට පිච්ච"},{"plant_id":"2","plant_min_price":"500.00","plant_max_price":"750.00","plant_short_description":"බඳුන් ගත කරන ලද රතු,කහ සහ සුදු අරලිය පැල","plant_description":"කොම්පෝස්ට් යොදා බඳුන් ගත කර ඇත. බන්දුනෙම තබා ගැනීමට වඩාත් සුදුසුය.","plant_image_url":"https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4068/4258135709_d18a001c5b_o.jpg","plant_availability":"false","plant_name":"බේබි අරලිය"}]}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is it adding all plants to their categories or is it adding 1 plant type to all categories?

Comment: When you select a category it lists all the plants available under that category

Comment: Yes, but you said: "When I'm clicking on one category it expand all the lists." This can have multiple causes

Comment: you are confusing me dude :)

Comment: Now you know how I feel. :D

Comment: "When I'm clicking on one category it expand all the lists." Tlhis is my problem .. What i need is when im clicking expand only the relevant list. not all.  Now what happening is if i click flowers it expand all the lists (vegetables,fruits,etc) filled with flowers :P

Comment: You are using `plant_cat.plant` for *every* category. If you assign a value to it, then every category will use that value. You need to assign the list of plants to the category, which was suggested by the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

you wanna repeat in one of the arrays in the repeating array so the code must be:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="cat_display" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="x in plant_cat">
        <button value={{x.cat_id}} type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="get_plants(x.cat_id)">{{x.cat_name}}</button> </br>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="y in x.plant">{{y.plant_name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

notice the second repeat is `y in x.plant`

Comment: I have changed it.. and also the JS script as follow             $scope.get_plants = function(cat_id)
            {
                alert(cat_id);
              $http.get("http://localhost:8080/Aggry/select_plant.php?cat_id="+cat_id)
                .then(function(response){
                  alert(response.data.records);
                    $scope.x.plant = response.data.records;                  
                });
            } but its not working :(

Comment: It says "angular.js:12520TypeError: Cannot set property 'plant' of undefined " when i inspect the console

Comment: Because `$scope.x` doesn't exist

Comment: So how can i define it then :(